# Hadoop up gradation and Fair scheduler

Tags: hadoop

I am using the fair scheduler in Hadoop 1.2, if I upgrade the Hadoop Version, will it keep the same fair scheduler or it will change to Hadoop 2 default one?

Thanks in advance